# Apache Tomcat wss websocket error during refresh

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, websocket

I'm noticing the following web socket error (https & wss) when refreshing our webpage. However, the same issue is not noticed when we run with regular 'ws'(http). With wss, the socket seems to be closing fine and before the next socket is opened, this warning is thrown.

It would be great if someone point out the issue here. Connections are closed at the right places. Is there anything special that needs to be done for wss before closing sockets?

```
cleaning up and closing socket connection with user: 7
session closed
03-Oct-2017 16:45:30.375 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-1]                                               org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doClose Failed to     close the ServletOutputStream connection cleanly
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:399)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:413)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doClose(NioServletOutputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.close(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doClose(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:139)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.close(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:667)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:348)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:290)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:131)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:71)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:647)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

New Websocket connection with user: 8
```